# Calculating standard error from minimax concave penalty (MCP)

Tags: standard-error, regularization

I am working on a high dimensional mediation analysis using the method in this paper. (Zhang H. 2016)

The idea is to

Step 1: Reduce the pool of potential mediators from a very large to a moderate number (i.e. less than the sample size);

Step 2: Conduct the variable selection with the minimax concave penalty (MCP);

Step 3: Carry out joint significance testing for mediation effects.

I have some questions about the calculation.

(1) In Step 1, the author used a method similar to sure independence screening (SIS), to select the top d = [2n/log(n)] largest absolute effects for mediator M with the response Y. (Fan,J. and Lv,J. 2008) I wonder whether this log is log10 or natural log, because I did not find any clear statement about this.

(2) In Step 3, the calculation of p-values involve calculating the standard error, based on the oracle property. I found the standard error formula in the paper by Fan, J. & Li, R. in 2001, but the math is very difficult for me. And I could not translate it into the R script.

I performed MCP in R using ncvreg package, and the function returns a list of objects including a vector of loss function results, a vector of ƛ, a matrix of B under each lambda, etc.

The standard error formula by Fan, J. & Li, R. in 2001 is as below

[image: standard error formula]

where

[image: standard error formula details]

The d is the number of variables included in the MCP.

The ℓ(B) in the formula is a loss function, which I think may be the vector of loss function results from MCP.

The pƛ() is the penalty function, dependent on different ƛ.

So my questions are

1) Why there are B0, B10, Bd0? Fan's paper states "Suppose that we are given an initial value B0 that is close to the minimizer of (3.6)" (The below formula)

[image: (3.6)]

2) I expect this formula to give me a list of standard error, corresponding to the variables. But the **diag** part seems to be a matrix to me.

3) My goal is to translate this into R script, it will be helpful if any one can give me some hints or thoughts in understanding this.

**Reference**

Fan,J. and Lv,J. Sure independence screening for ultrahigh dimensional feature space. J. Royal Stat. Soci. Ser. B, 70, 849–911. 2008

Fan, J. & Li, R. Variable Selection via Nonconcave Penalized Likelihood and Its Oracle Properties. . Journal of the American Statistical Association 96, 1348-1360. 2001

Zhang H. Estimating and testing high-dimensional mediation effects in epigenetic studies. Bioinformatics. 2016 Oct 15;32(20):3150-3154. Epub 2016 Jun 29. 2016